# Container test fails with Maven but succeeds with JUnit

Tags: java, docker, maven, junit, testcontainers

Facing an issue with running JUnit integration tests in IntelliJ IDEA (version `Community 2021.1`) through Maven (ver.`3.8.1`). My Docker Desktop version is `3.3.1 (63152)`. I am using Apple Macbook on M1 (ARM architecture).

The testcontainer is Postgre-based TimescaleDB (`timescale-pgcron:latest` is a prebuilt image in my Docker Desktop):

```
public class MyTimescaleContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<MyTimescaleContainer> {

    private MyTimescaleContainer() {
        super(DockerImageName.parse("timescale-pgcron").asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres").withTag("latest"));
    }

    public static MyTimescaleContainer getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        //do nothing, JVM handles shut down
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        static final MyTimescaleContainer INSTANCE = new MyTimescaleContainer()
                .withReuse(true)
                .waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck());
    }
}
```

Testcontainer dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I execute my test directly through JUnit (right click on my test package and press `Run 'Tests in '<my test package>''`), the container is spinned up normally and test successfully runs. However when I run it through Maven, it drops this:

```
[ERROR] com.mypackage.MyTest  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
        at com.mypackage.MyTest.startUp(MyTest.java:31)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=timescale-pgcron:latest, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
        at com.mypackage.MyTest.startUp(MyTest.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at com.mypackage.MyTest.startUp(MyTest.java:31)
```

Did anyone face this issue before?
The test also runs fine on CircleCI with these settings in the job that runs Maven (without these settings, the job fails with the same Docker error above):

```
machine:
  image: ubuntu-2004:202010-01
```

I initially thought that it might be related to Apple's M1 platform, since the vast majority of images does not support it, and this is actually bypassed through Docker's `--platform linux/amd64` flag, but I don't specify any flag when I run tests directly through JUnit, and it still successfully spins up containers. What's wrong with Maven then?

UPD.
This is a screenshot of `docker ps` when I run JUnit directly from `Run 'Tests in...'`, as you may see, `timescale-pgcron:latest` is spinned up:
[image]

Comment: Can you please try to use the latest Testcontainers version? At the time of writing this comment it's 1.15.3

Comment: @rieckpil tried `1.15.3`, still maven drops the same error

Comment: @rieckpil the only difference is that it drops only `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration`, i.e. `ContainerLaunchException/ContainerFetchException` are not dropped this time

Comment: `Could not find a valid Docker environment.`, is your Docker engine up- and running? What's the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: yes, it's up and running, `docker ps` prints out `CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES` if I don't run any containers. `Run 'Tests in...'` would fail if Docker was down, but it spins the container

Comment: @rieckpil I have attached the screenshot at the moment of running the test through `Run 'Tests in...'`, in the question

Answer (score 0):

just open terminal and type this command

sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock