# Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration

Tags: spring-boot, docker, macos, docker-compose, testcontainers

I am using the following:

- m2 Mac (OS X Ventura 13.3)
- Spring Boot v3.1.2
- Test Containers v1.19.1
- Docker Desktop v4.24.2

When I run my integration tests individually they pass but when running them with the following command:

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean package
```

I get the following error

`Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration`

I have tried everything in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173489/docker-socket-is-not-found-while-using-intellij-idea-and-docker-desktop-on-macos/77292592?noredirect=1#comment136266175_77292592) but nothing seems to be working.

Has anybody else managed to get it to work on an m2 Mac ?

Here is a sample of the integration test configuration

```java
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "36000")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class MyServiceIntegrationTests
{

     @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresqlContainer  = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.1-alpine");

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        postgresqlContainer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        postgresqlContainer.stop();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresqlContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresqlContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresqlContainer::getPassword);
    }
```

This is my docker file

```sh
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-18-slim AS build
RUN mkdir -p workspace
WORKDIR workspace
COPY pom.xml /workspace
COPY src /workspace/src
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:18-alpine
COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

It is being run using docker-compose and fails on this command

`RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package`

However, it works if I dont run the tests using docker-compose

Comment: This answer with 107 upvotes may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75782220/14072498

Comment: Is docker working properly ? For example, what's the output of `docker ps` ?

Comment: docker is running properly. The tests work when i run them individually in intellij but when i run them with mvn clean package they dont. @RoarS. I have tried the solution in that thread and it still doesnt work

Comment: This is a similar case, without any accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061837/container-test-fails-with-maven-but-succeeds-with-junit

Comment: That didnt work either

Comment: You may need to give more context, so that people can help. For example, how `mvn` interact with docker.

Comment: I have added the integration test config

Comment: Just to make sure this is not related to the repo in question; can you clone this small 
Postgres testcontainer demo repo and try to build that with Maven (I'm the owner of this repo)? https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/postgres-testcontainer-demo

Comment: That works, it must be an issue when running through docker-compose

Comment: You need the docker socket in the container running your tests. So, check https://java.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/#docker-in-docker